# simplest possible multifile download manager in qtreeview?

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qprogressbar

Im trying to make a download manager that can download multible files and shows them
in a qtreeview. Each item in qtreeview should show a filename, progressbar and status text of "Finished" after successfull download.

What is the most simplest and smallest amout code required to add these to qtreeview?

Comment: Take a look at the `torrent` example shipped with Qt.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/torrent-mainwindow-cpp.html and it seems that althought the class they use in that is named TorrentView it really is QTreeWidget not QTreeView. (I realized this when compiler complained about missing setHeaderLabels which QTreeView does not have). So for my case QTreeWidget is the right answer instead of QTreeView ?

Comment: A QTreeView is fine, the important bit in that example is the item delegate that draws a progressbar.

Comment: Yes. I see it now. This line  int progress = qobject_cast<MainWindow *>(parent())->clientForRow(index.row())->progress() seems to handle the updating but it's unclear to me who and when is this delegate class paint() method called??? By the way, what would have been correct way of setting headers if this torrent example would have used QTreeView instead ?

Comment: Just update your *model*, and emit the `dataChanged` signals. The delegate will then be asked to repaint itself by the view. About the headers: again, provide them in your model's `headerData`.